# How to handle load events and append in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hi I have a problem while using set interval function  with **.load** events and append please explain what I did mistake in my code please give a solution

**HTML**

```
<div id="user2<?php echo $d['qid'] ;?>">
```

Comments Loads Here

**Jquery code**

```
 setInterval(function(){

  $("#user2").load( "test2.php,#user2");

   },1000);
```

qid means Query id I have multiple(qid) queries in my site How to add append 
    please give a solution I am new in jquery Thanks in advance

Comment: You dont have any element with the ID = user2. The ID is user2<?php echo $d['qid'] ;?> for the element, but you can not have such ID

Comment: Not getting you

Comment: $('#user2').length will return 0 because there is no element with the ID user2

Comment: @Zorken17  see html code  div  element id with user2  whats wrong in that

Comment: The wrong is that I am not sure if you can have an ID with php in it, and if you can it will not only be user2 right? It will be user2 + qid and then jQuery will not find a element with ID user2.

Imagine a grup of people there some's name is Peter and someone else is PeterAlex. If you are searching for Peter, PeterAlex will not respond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id of div is dynamic, as "qid" is appended to it.

```html
<div id="user2<?php echo $d['qid'] ;?>">
```

In above code, if "$d['qid']" is 101, then generated html will be as given below.

```html
<div id="user2101">
```

Hence, your javascript must include dynamic id using "" syntax. Also, you should be using space instead of comma in load event (http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments). You should be passing "qid" to "test2.php" page as query string to get comments related to "qid".

```js
setInterval(function(){

  $("#user2<?php echo $d['qid'] ;?>").load( "test2.php #user2");

   },1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, as qid is the query id. Having the following code with qid 2 will yield

```
<div id="user22">
```

Is this really the div you really want? If you want `user2` it should be:

```
<div id="user<?php echo $d['qid'] ;?>">
```

Second, you need to pass a valid path to your page you want to load. Are you sure `test2.php,#user2` is the correct path?

Comment: I have 2 user types Like user1 =student,user2=Teacher

Comment: Not getting you. Can you please explain what you're trying to achieve with necessary information?

Comment: I have explained  problem with Load events  that too Live with Setinterval Function and append

Comment: Can you give us some sameple `qid`? Like what are the values that `qid` can have?

Comment: I have explained that too qid means  query id , query means student asked questions  you need anything  else